# Mongoose configuration problem with wemos d1 mini

Tags: mongoose, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to understand how to setup mongoose and mDash to control all over my devices. I'm really at the beginning and I'm having some trouble.

- I installed mongoose OS on my Mac and started mos tool
- I'm following the Doc (https://mdash.net/docs/) but any of the commands work.

I tried to connect to mDash with both mongoose OS and Arduino IDE

**Mongoose OS:**

Following the doc this is the command to flash the device:

```
mos flash https://mdash.net/downloads/ccm/ccm.esp32.zip --port SERIAL_PORT
```

But the zip file is for esp32 and on the wemos I got the esp8266, and the firmware for the esp8266 seams to be missing. Any of you ever tried to do this before?

Also if I try to run the command I get a 404 error:

```
$ mos flash https://mdash.net/downloads/ccm/ccm.esp32.zip --port /dev/cu.usbserial-1410
Fetching https://mdash.net/downloads/ccm/ccm.esp32.zip...
Error: /private/tmp/mos-20210208-36530-1bwv7ue/mos-9bf406d90c65fca0b377220940735015dcfbb76c/cli/ourutil/file.go:45: https://mdash.net/downloads/ccm/ccm.esp32.zip: failed to fetch: 404 Not Found
/private/tmp/mos-20210208-36530-1bwv7ue/mos-9bf406d90c65fca0b377220940735015dcfbb76c/common/fwbundle/fw_bundle_zip.go:51: 
/private/tmp/mos-20210208-36530-1bwv7ue/mos-9bf406d90c65fca0b377220940735015dcfbb76c/cli/flash.go:151: failed to load https://mdash.net/downloads/ccm/ccm.esp32.zip
/private/tmp/mos-20210208-36530-1bwv7ue/mos-9bf406d90c65fca0b377220940735015dcfbb76c/cli/main.go:198: flash failed
exit status 1
Command completed.
```

**Arduino IDE**

Even the DOC for the Arduino IDE is Esp32 based and I can't find any way to use the esp8266.

Any of you ever tried to use mongoose os and mDash with an esp8266? Thanks in advance